# How to transpose data from multiple rows to columns in excel

Tags: excel

I hope someone can help with this.

I need to convert data that is currently held in rows to a column. So there could be Part number 1 that has 5 different pieces of data currently held in 1 row. Example in the first image

[Current Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zvy9M.png)

I need part number 1 to be in column A 5 times with the different pieces of data in column B. Example in the second image.

[New setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQMpe.png)

I am able to do it the other way using the formula below but I can't get it to work in reverse.

=INDEX(Sheet1!$E:$E,SMALL(INDEX(($A3=Sheet1!$A:$A)*(MATCH(ROW(Sheet1!$A:$A), ROW(Sheet1!$A:$A)))+($A3<>Sheet1!$A:$A)*1048577,0,0),COLUMN(A3)))

Thank you

Comment: There are multiple solutions to your problem.  Search the forum and apply one of them.  For search terms you can use your topic (minus the "How to") or just the word "unpivot"

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that comes across this post I found the following formulas work.

To deal with your reference number and transpose use.
=OFFSET($A$2,FLOOR((ROW(A2)-ROW($A$2))/6,1),0)

To deal with your data and transpose use.
=OFFSET($B$2,FLOOR((ROW(B2)-ROW($B$2))/6,1),MOD(ROW(A2)-ROW($A$2),6))

Hope this helps